# Get Appended URL Values of Current Page - Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm playing around with Spring, and I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to get the appended variables of the current page's URL in my controller.  For instance, I edit an Address object in a jsp page, then submit it, and it goes to the correct method in my controller.  However, it's not passing the id value of the Address object that was just modified (but every other value is getting passed in correctly).  My page containing the form is getting the correct id value passed to it, and I've even created hidden input fields that contain the address id (the one I'm having issues with) and the contact id (which is getting set to the controller correctly).  What I'd like to know is how can I get the value of an appended variable from my form page's url in my corresponding controller method.  If that's not possible, then is there another way to get that value?

Here's my form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="editAddress.html">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input type="hidden" path="id" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.id}' />"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input type="hidden" path="contactId" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.contactId}' />"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="street">Street: </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="street" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.street}' />"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="city">City: </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="city" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.city}' />"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="state">State: </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="state" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.state}' />"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="zip">Zip: </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="zip" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.zip}' />"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="galaxy">Galaxy: </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="galaxy" placeholder="<c:out value='${command.galaxy}' />"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Update Address"/>
                <input type="button" value="Delete Address" action="deleteAddress.html" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</form:form>
```

And the url for this page ends with the following: /showAddress.html?id=3

Finally, here's my controller method that gets called:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editAddress")
public String updateAddress(@ModelAttribute("address") Address address, BindingResult result) { 


    //address param is coming from form values, not from a java obj
    int id = address.getId(); //not getting this value
    int contactId = address.getContactId(); //getting this correctly

    dbService.updateAddress(address);
    return "redirect:showContact.html?id=" + contactId;
}
```

id = 0, when it should be 3.  Any ideas?  I've played around with HttpServletResponse, HttpServletRequest, ModelAndView, HttpSession, etc but I can't seem to figure anything out.  Is this just a result of having poor app design?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Note: the value of id will change, as it's the PK for my address table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I overlooked this, but using HttpServletRequest's getParameter("id") did the trick.  Pass an HttpServletRequest object into the method as a parameter, the use String addressId = request.getParameter("id");  It works like a charm.